# How to manage single object of WebSocket using OkHttp in JobIntentService?

Tags: android, okhttp, jobintentservice

I had to replace Service due to Android Oreo issue and I am planning to use JobIntentService, but now JobIntentService is creating multiple connection of WebSocket in JobIntentService how can I prevent this?

Comment: Do not use JobIntentService as it is not for continous connection

Comment: @Selvin any suggestions ?

Comment: replace WebSocket  with FCM

Comment: We can't do it, because it is top level architecture. @Selvin